# Hardening node.js/nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, pci-compliance

For PCI requierements I need to hardening a node.js app or nginx server but I only found guides for IIS, Tomcat, operative systems, etc. [here you will find the available guides](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/multiform/index.cfm). My questions are:

- It's possible to hardening node.js?
- It's possible to hardening a nginx server?
- Is there any official documentation or trustworthy out
  there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example [dev-sec](http://dev-sec.io/) provides nginx hardening roles for puppet, ansible etc...

To harden a nodejs server the same principles should apply as hardening tomcat.
PCI-DSS lists a couple of things you need to do:

- Disable all unnecessary services.
- Leave only the necessary ports open.
  etc.

First make sure you develop your application according to best practises from a security point of view. For instance, SSL/TLS, CSRF, Error handling, use SNYK or similar, as described [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-security-checklist/).

Talk to your QSA about the requirements.